# Why isn't my variable initialized in this code?

Tags: java

I keep getting an error that the variable `temp` might not have been initialized. I don't get it - I have it initialized, what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseDigit
{
   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int num;    //variable to hold the current number
      int temp;   //variable to hold the temporary number

      System.out.print("Enter a positive interger: ");

     do
     { 
      num = console.nextInt();
      temp = reverseDigit(temp, num);
     }
     while (num > 0);

      System.out.print(" " + temp + " ");
    }

    public static int reverseDigit(int temp, int num)
    {
        temp = num % 10;      
        num = num / 10;       
        return num;
    }              
}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated, but instead of long comments on variable names, just name them better, like `currentNumber` and `tempNumber`, or `currNum` and `tempNum`, etc. Also note that I'm not convinced this does what you want it to, since you keep overwriting `temp`, only printing it out when you're all done.

Comment: You are trying to initialize temp, with a method call that take temp as parameter.

Comment: It's not clear what your `reverseDigit` method is trying to do with `temp`, but you're basically just going to return `num / 10`. The value of `temp` is completely ignored and pointless. You should rethink your whole design at this point - think about what you really want `reverseDigit` to do in terms of input and output. Once you've figured that out and adjusted your code, I strongly suspect that the problem you're talking about here will go away...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int temp = 0;    
do
     { 
      num = console.nextInt();
      temp = reverseDigit(temp, num);
     }
     while (num > 0);

      System.out.print(" " + temp + " ");
```

Comment: I am trying to write a method that takes an integer as a parameter and displays the digits in reverse. I wrote a program for an earlier assignment that did that. I also needed to write a program to test the method. When I run my program I get the prompt to input the integer but I am not calling the method correctly because that's all it does. Your suggestion to initialize temp = 0 helped. The program executes to the point of asking for my input but doesn't call the method. This is where I'm lost. I've looked at many examples in my text but I'm still not calling the method correctly. @helppro

Comment: I got it! I just had to move my do...while loop. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize temp at the start of the method :

```
 int temp = 0;
```

This way you won't access it before it's initialized.

Comment: `console.nextInt` initialize `num`, not `temp`.

Comment: The OP is calling `temp =  reverseDigit(temp, num);`, so he's trying to initialize `temp` with a method call that takes `temp` as parameter. Since the arguments are evaluated first, that's the problem.

Comment: That took care of the error I was getting, but now my program isn't executing through right. I am trying to write a method that takes an integer as a parameter and displays the digits in reverse and a program to test it. I wrote a program for an earlier assignment that did that. When I run it I get the prompt to input the integer but I am not calling the method correctly because that's all it does. The program executes to the point of asking for my input. It is calling the method but I've messed up my original program the loop now I only get the last digit. Maybe a while loop?suggestions @Eran

Comment: I got it! I just had to move my do...while loop. Thanks for the help